# iOS MapKit creating Pin loading from external file

Tags: ios, mapkit, coordinates, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

i'm building an app based on MapKit. I want to create a certain number of pin (let's say 20) and now i'm specifying those coordinates by code. For example, in my implementation file:

```
#define PIN1_LATITUDE 43.504156 
#define PIN1_LONGITUDE 12.343405

#define PIN2_LATITUDE 43.451696
#define PIN2_LONGITUDE 12.488599
```

and so on for all 20 values. The problem is that, i would like to load and display different sets of 20 pins, based on a certain parameter. So I would like to store pin's coordinates on external file and load 1 set at time.

it's possibile to do that? which structure should I use?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom object Class for pin and other datas. and Store them in Array or dictionary . And use whenever you need . You can use persistent storage also .

.h

```
@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject 
@property(nonatomic, assign)    double latitude;
@property(nonatomic, assign)    double longitude;
@property (nonatomic)           int Id;
@end
```

.m

```
 @interface MapAnnotation 
      @synthesize latitude,longitude,Id;
    @end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
 NSMutableArray *annotationarray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 MapAnnotation *newAnnoataion = [[MapAnnotation allo]init];
 newAnnoataion.latitude = 49.05678;
 newAnnoataion.longitude = 69.05678;
 newAnnoataion.id = 1;
[annotationarray addObject newAnnoataion];
```

Comment: I dont get it.. can you give me some examples?

Comment: Like this you can create.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a PLIST file or json file for the 20 pins lat & lng values
- You will need [JSONKit lib](http://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) or preferably ios framework class [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) if you App is targeting iOS5 and later
- Add the file to the project resource folder
- Write code that will load the resource file

Here is an example how to do that using JSONKit

Create a json file, copy paste the following json sample into a **poi_data.json**, the load the json file.

```
    {
        "poi": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "lat": "43.668997",
                "lng": "-79.385093"
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "lat": "43.668997",
                "lng": "-79.385093"
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "lat": "43.668997",
                "lng": "-79.385093"
            }
        ]
    }



    - (void)loadDataFromFile {
        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"poi_data"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];
        NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                         error:NULL];

        NSDictionary *poiCollection = [content objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionUnicodeNewlines | JKParseOptionLooseUnicode error:nil];



            NSArray* pois = [result objectForKey:@"poi"];
                for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [pois count]; i++) {

                    NSDictionary* node = (NSDictionary*)[poi objectAtIndex:i];

                    CGFloat lat = [[node objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
                    CGFloat lng = [[node objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
            } 
}
```

- You can also use PLIST and load into a NSDictionary, plist is very
  well supported in Cocoa Touch.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5

**Remember to run the load data code in background thread or NSOperation block, your app possibly will crash - kicked out by springboard - for taking too long to load up.**